# why this code does not run alert ("out of loop")

Tags: javascript

why this code does not run alert ("out of loop")? it is inside function block and out of for loop, so after fnishing loop next statment that is alert ("out of loop") must run. so why it doesnt run when both inputs are true (user:Amir.Nassaji   pass: aaaaaaaaaaaa)

```
<body >
<form onsubmit="return loginCheck()" action= "#" 
method="Post">
username:<input type= "text" name= "username" class= "login" /><span class= "validation"></span><br />
password:<input type= "password" name= "password"  class= "login"/><span class= "validation"></span><br />
<input type= "submit" value= "submit" />
</form>



<script>
"using strict";
function loginCheck() {
  var fault = "";
  var ides = ["username" , "password"];   
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("login");
  var inputSpans = document.getElementsByClassName("validation");
  var i = 0;
  for(i; i<inputs.length ; i++) {

    var inputValue = inputs[i].value;
    try {
      inputSpans[i].innerHTML = "";
      if (inputs[i].value === "") {
        throw " fild " + ides[i] + " is required.";
      }
      if (inputs[i].value.length < 8) {
        throw ides[i] + " must have at least 8 char length.";
      }
      if (!inputs[i].value.search(/^\d/i) && i === 0) {
        throw  ides [i] + " this filed can't start with number";
      }
      if (inputs[i].value.search(/[~!@#$%^&*\/><":;',()+=-]/i) !== -1 && i === 0) {
        throw  ides [i] + " there is unaccepted chars in field. ";
      }

    } catch(err) {

      inputSpans[i].innerHTML = "*" + " " + err;
      fault = err;
    } finally {
      alert (i+": finally run " + fault); // this is for testing running finally
      if ( i === 1 && fault != null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }

  }
  alert ("out of loop");

}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: why it doesn't run even when there isn't any thrown error

Comment: It does get run if you make a call to `loginCheck()`

Comment: Its getting ran, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/8/

Comment: `if ( i === 1 && fault != null)` if that condition is met then you have `return false;` which would end execution of the function and the alert would not happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one input see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/11/

**The alert is triggered**

If you have two inputs see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/10/

**The alert is not triggered**

This conditional is saying if more then one input return `false` and the last `alert()` will not be called

```
if ( i === 1 && fault != null) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right while there is fault, check the right code is this:https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/24/  could you please check it while user: Amir.Nassaji pass: aaaaaaaaaa

Comment: thanks  I found the problem. I replaced var fault = null instead var fault = "" and the problem solved